# WebsiteTtransfer - site not working

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection, transfer

I'm trying to transfer a website, from remote to local.
I downloaded the files by FTP and uploaded in MAMP/htdocs, then I exported the database and imported it in local. 
I opend the website and there is a page that says

```
exec($sqlinterr, __LINE__); $row = null; $numRec = $_DB->loadObject($row); $num = 0; if($numRec > 0){ $vai = 0; $fat = @split(";", $row->pagine); if($fat[0] > 0) return $fat[0]; } } return $params['idpage']; }  etc...
```

Is it a problem of database connection?

This is the config.db.php file:

```
<?php
    $host_db="localhost";

//$user_db="xxx";
$user_db="dmntdb";
//$pwd_db="yyy";
$pwd_db="xyz";

//$name_db="yyy";
$name_db="ddd2010";

$dirSite = "/home/3484981039/works/web/ladiamantina";

$TSYS_tables = "sys_tables";
?>
```

What could I do to fix the problem? Thank you!

Comment: If you're seeing the code on the webpage, then either you're not opening it correctly (make sure the URL in the address bar starts with http, not file) or MAMP is not set up to execute PHP.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I use MAMP for other php websites too, and it works... I open the website from localhost:8888, selecting it from the list of my local websites...